# Python - Pandas - Windows - Terminal - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Tags: python, pandas, windows, visual-studio-code, terminal

Has anyone already seen this kind of issue?

aula1.py

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'nome':['Rafael','Maria',"João"],
'idade':[10,20,30]})
print(df)
```

When I run this script in Terminal, I get this error:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

Experimente a nova plataforma cruzada PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\caiov\Desktop\curso_pandas>  & 'C:\Users\caiov\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.9.exe' 'c:\Users\caiov\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.5.842923320\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '52784' '--' 'c:\Users\caiov\Desktop\curso_pandas\aula1.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\caiov\Desktop\curso_pandas\aula1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
PS C:\Users\caiov\Desktop\curso_pandas>
```

I checked pandas installation and it's fine (I think).

```
PS C:\Users\caiov\Desktop\curso_pandas> pip show pandas
Name: pandas
Version: 1.2.4
Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics 
Home-page: https://pandas.pydata.org
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\caiov\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
Requires: pytz, python-dateutil, numpy
Required-by:
PS C:\Users\caiov\Desktop\curso_pandas>
```

does anyone have some advice for me?

```
PS C:\Users\caiov\Desktop\curso_pandas> pip show pandas
Name: pandas
Version: 1.2.4
Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics 
Home-page: https://pandas.pydata.org
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\caiov\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
Requires: pytz, python-dateutil, numpy
Required-by:
PS C:\Users\caiov\Desktop\curso_pandas> pip install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\caiov\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (1.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in c:\users\caiov\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\users\caiov\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.5 in c:\users\caiov\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.20.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\caiov\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.15.0)
PS C:\Users\caiov\Desktop\curso_pandas> pip3 install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\caiov\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (1.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.5 in c:\users\caiov\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.20.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\users\caiov\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in c:\users\caiov\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\caiov\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.15.0)
PS C:\Users\caiov\Desktop\curso_pandas>
```

When I run on Output window I get this result:

[image: Outputwindow]

Comment: Do you have several python versions on your machine? Have you checked the interpreter you use in your IDE is python.3.9?

Comment: Man, you nailed it! Thanks for the help. I discover another python instalation.